# Could not load type from assembly error in Visual Studio 2013 & 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Need your help guys. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I have a project that runs fine on Visual Studio 2012. But when I try to use one of the newer visual studio IDEs (2013 or 2015) I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'XXX.Security.Shared.Logging.Logger' from assembly
>   'XXX.Security.Shared, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'XXX.Security.Shared.Logging.Logger' from assembly
>   'XXX.Security.Shared, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>   XXX.Security.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.InitializeModule(HttpApplication
>   context) +0
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.HttpModuleBase.Init(HttpApplication
>   context) +34
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type
>   'XXX.Security.Shared.Logging.Logger' from assembly
>   'XXX.Security.Shared, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947444 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261

What on earth do I need to change? Here is the relevant web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="XXX.Security.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, XXX.Security.IdentityModel" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="XXX.Security.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, XXX.Security.IdentityModel" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
```

I have tried & tried & tried. For months. So I have been stuck on VS2012 because of it. What do you guys think? I really appreciate any input.

Comment: This can sometimes be an x64/x86 conflict. Are you building to the same platform as the OS you're on?

Comment: I have set the project to build for 'any CPU'. Should I try changing it to x64 specifically?

Comment: Yes. Any CPU is _sometimes_ ok, but more often than not if you are using outside assemblies, they have been built specifically for x86/x64. I would generally just build to a specific platform in Visual Studio.

Comment: When I switch it over to x64 it gives a different error. Definitely seems to work better when I compile for 'any cpu'. The project runs fine when compiled in VS2012 with this setting,

Comment: Update: After I started using VS2017 this issue disappeared.